# What RPM package do I need to install to have GObject documentaion available locally on RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, gtk, c++

I want the documentation at https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/index.html to be available on my local RHEL 7 machine in `/usr/share/`.  What is the name of the package that I need to install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From that link "gtype" looks good to search for in the `yum` database

```
$ yum whatprovides '*/gobject/*' | egrep 'gtype.*html'
Filename    : /usr/share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gtype-non-instantiable.html
Filename    : /usr/share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gtype-non-instantiable-classed.html
Filename    : /usr/share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/chapter-gtype.html
Filename    : /usr/share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gtype-instantiable-classed.html
Filename    : /usr/share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gtype-conventions.html
```

`chapter-gtype.html` looks like a good hit, so

```
$ yum whatprovides /usr/share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/chapter-gtype.html
...
glib2-doc-2.54.2-2.el7.noarch : A library of handy utility functions
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/chapter-gtype.html
```

so it's probably the `glib2-doc` package.

Comment: Yes. GObject is part of GLib.

Comment: Well done!  In Oracle Linux 7, you have to enable the Optional yum repo for the commands above to work and to use yum to install.